# Show next array value at a certain time

Tags: php

I want to show one value from my array until a certain time is reached (every morning at 5:00 am). If this time is reached the next value from my array should be shown.

After the last value of the array was reached the script should start (automatically) with the first array value, again.

Example:

**My array**

```
$eventschedule = array("apple", "banana", "mango", "peach");
```

Loop should work like that:

```
**Schedule**                     | **Shown array value**
27.12. 5:00 am - 28.12. 4:59 am  | apple
28.12. 5:00 am - 29.12. 4:59 am  | banana
29.12. 5:00 am - 30.12. 4:59 am  | mango
30.12. 5:00 am - 31.12. 4:59 am  | peach
31.12. 5:00 am - 01.01. 4:59 am  | apple  | **loop should start again**
```

I think this could be achieved within a loop (maybe there is a better solution), but I don't know how to express the condition, that the script should get the next arrays' value every day at 5:00 am.

```
$eventschedule = array("apple", "banana", "mango", "peach");

$currenttime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$nextevent = date('Y-m-d 5:00', strtotime(' +1 day'));

$i = 0;
    while ($i <= 3) {
      if ($currenttime < $nextevent) {
        echo $eventschedule[$i];
        $i++;
      }
  }
```

Comment: No loop needed. You have a start date and `n` items. Find how many days between “now” and the start date, and look into “mod” to get the circular math

Comment: Does that script runs continuously, or it should keep it's memory between executions?

Comment: @user19513069 The script runs continuously so it shouldn't need a memory.

Comment: Shouldn't $currenttime be updated inside the loop? Also, I'd like to give a little frame challenge: isn't this something easier done with cron, or a manager script to run it? Or, like @ChrisHaas said, run daily at 5:00 and count the days since? (Nevertheless, I'll try to answer your question as posted now)

Answer (score 1):

I'll deal mostly with the **logic side** of things, but I'd like to add that maybe your problem could be solved in other ways, or at least improve in some ways. For example: There's no sleep in your code? If the time did not arrive yet, it should check for the next one?

There's 2 solutions that I see, although they have the same basis: loop the array indefinitely. But, there are some little changes in implementation details:

1. **Nested Loops:** Use `while (true)` and a second loop internally (a `while` like you use, or a `for`/`foreach`).
2. **Flattened Loop with modulo:** Use `while (true) { $i = ($i + 1) % count($eventschedule); }` with your logic after the `$i`.

I'll show only the loop part of the code, assume that `$eventschedule`, `$currenttime` and `$nextevent` are already defined.

#### Nested Loops

I'll use nested `while` just because that's what you used, but otherwise I'd recommend using `foreach`.

```
while (true) {
  $i = 0;
  while ($i <= 3) { // could be generalized to $i <= count($eventschedule)
                    // or even better: changed to foreach
    if ($currenttime < $nextevent) {
      echo $eventschedule[$i];
      $i++;
    }
  }
}
```

### Flattened Loop with modulo

The idea is that when $i = 4, it'll loop back to 0.

```
$i = 0;
while (true) {
  if ($currenttime < $nextevent) {
    echo $eventschedule[$i];
    $i = ($i + 1) % 4; // or % count($eventschedule);

    // this is equivalent to:
    /*
    $i++;
    if ($i == 4) {
      $i = 0;
    }
    */

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to get your "nested loop" solution to work.  You are using an indefinite loop. As you wrote I need some kind of a sleep function which should check if the time arrived to get the next array value. 
Would I use `time_sleep_until` therefore or how would I implement that correctly?

Comment: I think I'd use a simple sleep (after the if). Also, as I asked in the comments, I believe that you should update `$currenttime` inside the loop, right?